# Express js 4x :req.params returns empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Trying to get URl parameters in express js,but got empty object.

```
var password= require('./routes/password');
app.use('/reset/:token',password);
```

**password.js**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params);
    res.send(req.params);
});
```

`console.log(req.params)` output is  `{}`

Access url :`http://localhost:3000/reset/CiVv6U9HUPlES3i0eUsNwK9zb7xVZpfHsQNuzMNWqLlGA4NJKoagwbcyiUZ8`

Comment: What is the `router`? You have initialized a new route on it `router.get`

Comment: router is implemented `var router = express.Router();
`

Comment: You have to show the initialization of `password.js`, you're not actually providing function to your route

Answer (score 26):

By default, nested routers do not get passed any parameters that are used in mountpaths from their parent routers.

In your case, `app` is the parent router, which uses `/reset/:token` as a mountpath, and `router` is the nested router.

If you want `router` to be able to access `req.params.token`, create it as follows:

```
let router = express.Router({ mergeParams : true });
```

Documented [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.router).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting params and query mixed up.

**Query approach**

Your code should look like this when using query values for the example url: [www.example.com?token=123&foo=bar](http://www.example.com?token=123&foo=bar)

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.query);
    console.log(req.query.token); // to log value of token
    console.log(req.query.foo);   // to log value of foo
    res.send(req.query);
});
```

**Params approach**

Your code should look like this when using params values for the example url: [www.example.com/123](http://www.example.com/123)

```
router.get('/:token', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params);
    console.log(req.params.token); // to log value of token
    res.send(req.params);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use a middleware to log the path params:

```
const logger = (req, res, next)=>{
  console.log(req.params)
  res.send(req.params)
  next()//<----very important to call it.
};

app.use(logger); //<----use to apply in the app

router.get('/', (req, res, next)=>res.send('Logged.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you messed it up a little bit. You have to pass instance of `express` to your module.

**Server.js**:

```
//adding modules
require('./routes/password')(app);
```

**Password.js**:

```
module.exports = function(router) {
    router.get('/reset/:token', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.params);
        res.send(req.params);
    });

    //and so on.. your routes go here
}
```